# Limit admin add user in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite. I want to set a limit for admins to add users to their own subsite

For example, admin can create 5 users on a.mysite.com, and other admin can create 10 users on b.mysite.com.
How is this possible?
I am already grateful for your help. Healthy days..

Comment: Add another table with columns  like `user_id`, `number_of_sub_users`, and `sub_user_limit`. When the admin adds a new user, increment the number of sub users, as long as it's under the limit, otherwise block the function that's calling `wp_insert_user` (there's no `pre_user_insert`) hook, only `user_registered`, so you'll need to invoke this manually. It's far beyond the breadth of what we can provide here on StackOverflow, but that's the basic flow I would follow.